# Is there a tool to run CSS 1 line at a time?

Tags: css

I want to see how the site would load on very slow connections.

Answer (score 6):

Don't know about the specific answer to your question, but how about a tool that would simulate a slow connection [Firefox Throttle](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/5917) from [previous SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/473465/firefox-plugin-to-simulate-slow-internet-connection-or-limit-bandwidth)

Answer (score 6):

CSS isn't downloaded and "run" 1 line at a time. The whole CSS is parsed at once after downloading and the styles are applied to the whole document tree.

Comment: I'm currently testing the site in opera, and things are changing all over the place.

Comment: You sure that isn't because the HTML is loading slowly, not the CSS?

Comment: That's likely more the HTML and images, not the CSS.

Answer (score 1):

Is that even how CSS would be handled across a slow connection?  I don't know the answer to that, but you'd probably be better of using some kind of a proxy tool to simulate slow connections.

I know [Charles](http://www.charlesproxy.com/documentation/using-charles/throttling/) has this feature.

Answer (score 0):

There is no line by line processing but for sure browsers implement algorithms for partially parsing and rendering blocks of CSS code even I don't think you can simulate this effect by throttling connections.